# Problemas al cargar un String con espacios desde un .dat

Tags: c++, fstream

En esta ocasión estoy teniendo un problema con el siguiente código, "funciona" correctamente, guarda los datos en el archivo .dat y también los carga correctamente, pero lo que no entiendo muy bien, es porque cuando ingreso un `string` que contenga un espacio, el programa se queda repitiendo infinitamente el `while` del método `Cargar()`, quisiera entender porque da ese problema cuando el string posee un espacio, y como pudiera solucionarlo?

Tenia la idea de ingresar un guion bajo remplazando cada espacio antes de guardarlo, y remover los guiones bajos a la hora de cargarlos, pero eso es un escape al problema, no una solución (no es lo mismo rodear una montaña que escalarla)

Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct Estudiante {
    int id;
    string nombre;
};

Estudiante parseSource(ifstream &source) {
    int id;
    string nombre;

    source >> id >> nombre;

    Estudiante estudiante_temp;
    estudiante_temp.id = id;
    estudiante_temp.nombre = nombre;

    return estudiante_temp;
}

void Escribir(vector<Estudiante> estudiantes){
    ofstream escritor;
    escritor.open("estudiantes.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
    for (int i = 0; i < estudiantes.size(); i++){
        if(i != 0){
            escritor << endl;
        }
        escritor << estudiantes.at(i).id << setw(50) << estudiantes.at(i).nombre;
    } 
    escritor.close();
}

vector<Estudiante> Cargar(){
    vector<Estudiante> estudiantes;
    ifstream lector;
    lector.open("estudiantes.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
    while (!lector.eof()) {
        estudiantes.push_back(parseSource(lector));
    }
    lector.close();
    return estudiantes;
}

int main() {
    //vector que almacena todo
    vector<Estudiante> estudiantes;

    Estudiante new_estudiante1;
    new_estudiante1.id = 1;
    new_estudiante1.nombre = "Nombre_completo_1";
    estudiantes.push_back(new_estudiante1);

    Estudiante new_estudiante2;
    new_estudiante2.id = 2;
    new_estudiante2.nombre = "Nombre_completo_2";
    estudiantes.push_back(new_estudiante2);

    Estudiante new_estudiante3;
    new_estudiante3.id = 3;
    new_estudiante3.nombre = "Nombre_completo_3";
    estudiantes.push_back(new_estudiante3);

    Escribir(estudiantes);
    cout << "size: " << estudiantes.size() << endl;
    estudiantes.clear();
    cout << "size: " << estudiantes.size() << endl;
    estudiantes = Cargar();
    cout << "size: " << estudiantes.size() << endl;

    //mostrando los datos
    cout<<"Estudiantes (" << estudiantes.size() << "):"<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i < estudiantes.size(); i++) {
        cout << "{";
        cout << "id: " << estudiantes.at(i).id << ", ";
        cout << "nombre: " << estudiantes.at(i).nombre;
        cout << "}" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el formato del archivo de datos?

Comment: Ummm .dat..? o no entendi bien tu pregunta?

Comment: `.dat` es la extensión de tu archivo, quiero saber cómo están los datos en el archivo, sea cual sea su extensión.

Comment: 1 (31 espacios) Nombre_completo_1
2 (31 espacios) Nombre_completo_2
3 (31 espacios) Nombre_completo_3

exactamente asi aparece cuando abro el .dat en VScode, claro con los respectivos saltos de linea que no puedo mostrar en un comentario

Answer (score 1):

Es normal que tengas problemas al cargar cadenas de caracteres con espacios desde un archivo si usas espacios como separador de campos:

> ```
> 1 (31 espacios) Nombre_completo_1 2 (31 espacios) Nombre_completo_2 3 (31 espacios) Nombre_completo_3
> ```

Mi consejo es que cambies el formato del archivo a:

> ```
> 1 Nombre_completo_1 (salto de línea)
> 2 Nombre_completo_2 (salto de línea)
> 3 Nombre_completo_3
> ```

Como mejoras adicionales haría también lo siguiente:

1. Crear operadores de lectura y escritura desde/a flujo de datos para `Estudiante`:

   ```
   struct Estudiante {
       int id;
       string nombre;
   };

   std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &i, Estudiante &e) {
       i >> e.id;
       return std::getline(i, e.nombre);
   }
   std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Estudiante &e) {
       return o << e.id << ' ' << e.nombre;
   }
   ```
2. Crear un alias para el vector de `Estudiante` con el fin de facilitar trabajar con ese tipo de datos:

   ```
   using v_estudiantes = std::vector<Estudiante>;
   ```
3. Renombrar las funciones `parseSource` y `Escribir` para que no tengan un remix de idiomas en el nombre y para trabajar con rutas de archivo en lugar de con flujos de datos:

   ```
   v_estudiantes Cargar(const std::string &ruta) {

       v_estudiantes resultado;

       if (std::ifstream archivo{ruta}) {
           Estudiante e;
           while (archivo >> e) {
               resultado.push_back(e);
           }
       }

       return resultado;
   }

   void Guardar(const v_estudiantes &estudiantes, const std::string &ruta) {
       if (std::ofstream archivo{ruta}) {
           for (const auto &e : estudiantes) {
               archivo << e << '\n';
           }
       }
   }
   ```

De esta manera, tu código [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVPbitswEH22vmJwIetAGnp5s12/tKXQp/2AwqKVlUTU0QRZSinB356OLNmRk4Xa4MsZzZw5ZyRxOr3fC3G9vlNadK6VUCvsrZH82LAbRojS@xTZPS46S2HRNIxRyAkL33vrWsW1lXBhQJfSFlRbjd@9bcsylAWNx1cjKzZUPpdwFYrDCk/ScF@0KZYBtUnLr@R6ooCmAbmdWIy0zuhAtpe2U1oWlCq3gXJNnIER7xnrurgLbECg7u3bvJEIoa5Hev9@onv8nfUx5nov@Pwi5yI9fAn9BfvqW/mG7Fiu/MrNnpsi9JE6uDLOct/L2MwyycjedZa3WIWo2kE0M84QuBEHdcaLLzJMivyVSJXVjP45qE5CEbNGw9OkYEfk3J5cf3h55eJ34d2e4gMLz9S7pE8KnJFM/OG4aWfBS1mr5GcazZuWLDTjfzXv0EAk5M4i8UAJCde91MkGP@lx6r/006NQUuR3/5ErXfgK2SSNPrPLxw3kP/Gg4RvKfNh46JOHuJYJ9JmgZ2mUQKDj1mEPz7xDaikfWDZQMOly23Kbk@Ese9RzG2o57ajH1DUxjo4JdNbrypPNoPNR7gzEDZ@DcH8xHmcKl3C/LoZmm1gWh/@Bhn69/gM):

```
int main() {
    Guardar({
        {1, "John Doe"},
        {2, "Jane Doe"},
        {3, "Perico de los Palotes"}
    }, "estudiantes.dat");

    for (const auto &estudiante : Cargar("estudiantes.dat"))
        std::cout << "{id: " << estudiante.id << ", nombre: " << estudiante.nombre << "}\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Otras cosas a tener en cuenta:

1. No estas guardando datos en binario, ergo no es necesario `ios::binary` para abrir el archivo.
2. Los `std::ofstream` ya son flujos de dato de salida (**o**utput **f**ile **stream**), ergo no es necesario `ios::out` para abrir el archivo.
3. Los `std::ifstream` ya son flujos de dato de entrada (**i**nput **f**ile **stream**), ergo no es necesario `ios::in` para abrir el archivo.
4. Si no tienes intención de modificar un dato, deberías marcarlo como `const`.
5. Usa referencias para evitar copiar contenedores, su copia es muy costosa.